# how to store struct in a text file in c++

Tags: c++, struct, file-handling

I want to store the elements of struct into a text file. I have multiple inputs and this is what I have done, however, I can only store the latest inputs but not all the input. Thanks in advance for the help! Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct ProcessRecords {
    string ID;
    int arrival;
    int wait;
    int burst;
    
    void putToFile() {
        ofstream input;
        input.open ("process.txt");
        input << ID << "\t" << arrival << "\t" << wait << "\t" << burst << endl;
        input.close();
    }
};

int main() {
    int numProcess;
    int algo;
    
    cout << "\n\t\t=== CPU SCHEDULING ALGORITHMS ===\n";
    cout << "\n\t\tEnter number of processes: ";
    cin >> numProcess;
    ProcessRecords process[numProcess]; 
    string processID[numProcess];
    int arrTime[numProcess];
    int waitTime[numProcess];
    int burstTime[numProcess];
    cout << endl << endl;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numProcess; i++) {
        cout << "\n\tEnter process ID for Process " << i+1 << ":\t ";
        cin >> processID[i];
        process[i].ID = processID[i];
        cout << "\n\t\tEnter arrival time for " << processID[i] << ":\t ";
        cin >> arrTime[i];
        process[i].arrival = arrTime[i];
        cout << "\n\t\tEnter waiting time for " << processID[i] << ":\t ";
        cin >> waitTime[i];
        process[i].wait = waitTime[i];
        cout << "\n\t\tEnter burst time for " << processID[i] << ":\t ";
        cin >> burstTime[i];
        process[i].burst = burstTime[i];
        process[i].putToFile();
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my sample output:
[image]

Comment: The default mode for opening a file is to overwrite it, and you open the file each time you call `putToFile`. Look into opening a file to **append**.

Comment: I guess that you are not aware of this, what you are implementing is called serialization (reading/writing a struct's data to file) and there are c++ serialization libraries you can (and should in real life code) use. This is not a direct answer to your question but it is good for you to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First In C++(by C++ i mean standard C++ and not extensions), the size of an array must be a **compile time constant**. So you cannot write code like:

```
int n = 10;
int arr[n];    //incorrect
```

Correct way to write this would be:

```
const int n = 10;
int arr[n];    //correct
```

For the same reason the following statement is incorrect in your code :

```
int arrTime[numProcess]; //incorrect because size of array must be fixed and decide at compile time
```

Second you should append to the text file instead of overwriting it. For opening the file in append mode you can use:

```
input.open("process.txt", ofstream::app);
```

You can check [here](https://onlinegdb.com/LdqP4Yppy) that the program works(append) as you desire, using `input.open("process.txt", ofstream::app);` . Also do note what i said about the size of array being compile time constant. I have not changed it in the link i have given. You can use `std::vector` for variable size container.

Comment: It's worth mentioning the C does have *variable length arrays*, so many compilers support this as an extension in C++. It's not usually the recommended thing to use in C++ though.

Comment: thanks for correcting me with the array!
with regards to the append, can you show me an example on code? I have no idea on the append function. sorry

Comment: @BoBTFish The first 3 words of my answers are "First In C++" so i am talking about standard C++ and not about C or any kind of extensions.

Comment: @peanutbutter For opening the file in append mode you can use `input.open("process.txt", ofstream::app);
`  I have added the same thing in my answer, check it out.

Comment: @AnoopRana Your answer is technically correct, but I was suggesting a way it could be more helpful to the asker. They are obviously a beginner and might be surprised why you are telling them something is impossible even though it seems to work for them.

Comment: @peanutbutter Also note that you don't have to explicitly call `close` on the `stream` as the destructor will do that for you.

Comment: @BoBTFish The OP seems to get what i said about arrays, so i thing its ok. Also i have added in brackets that by C++ i mean C++ standard and not any extensions. So i think now you will be fine with it.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! I really appreciate it and it was really helpful. I will keep in mind what guys have said about my question.

Comment: Even better, use the usual C++ idiom of std::vector ie replace ProcessRecords process[numProcess] with a vector<ProcessRecords>process

Comment: Excellent answer, IMO you only missed mentioning that the OP wastes a lot of space by using arrays for each input temporary, eg delete arrTime[], waitTime[], burstTime[], and add "int arrTime;int waitTime;int burstTime" inside the for loop

Comment: @pattakosn Thanks. I mentioned the use of `std::vector` at the end of my answer.